# How to fill a contour plot mask and retain data inside the contour and blackout the rest

Tags: python, image, opencv, mask, contour

I have an image like so,
[image]

By using the following code,

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# load the image
image = cv2.imread("frame50.jpg", 1)

#color boundaries [B, G, R]
lower = [0, 3, 30]
upper = [30, 117, 253]

# create NumPy arrays from the boundaries
lower = np.array(lower, dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array(upper, dtype="uint8")

# find the colors within the specified boundaries and apply
# the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask, 50, 255, 0)
if (int(cv2.__version__[0]) > 3):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
else:
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

if len(contours) != 0:
    # find the biggest countour (c) by the area
    c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow('ROI',ROI)
cv2.imwrite('ROI.png',ROI)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I get the following cropped image,

[image]

I would like to retain all data within the orange hand-drawn boundary including the boundary itself and blackout the rest.
In the image above the data outside the orange boundary is still there. I do not want that. How do i fill the mask which is like this now so that i can retain data inside the orange boundary,

[image]

I would still like to retain other properties like the rectangular bounding box. I don't want anything else to change. How do I go about this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you desire (in your comments to my previous answer) to have the outer region to be black rather than transparent, you can do that as follows in Python/OpenCV with a couple of lines changed to multiply the mask by the input rather than put the mask into the alpha channel.

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# load the image
image = cv2.imread("frame50.jpg")

#color boundaries [B, G, R]
lower = (0, 70, 210)
upper = (50, 130, 255)

# threshold on orange color
thresh = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(big_contour)

# draw filled contour on black background
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

# apply mask to input image
new_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

# crop 
ROI = new_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
   
# save result 
cv2.imwrite('frame50_thresh.jpg',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('frame50_mask.jpg',mask)
cv2.imwrite('frame50_new_image2.jpg',new_image)
cv2.imwrite('frame50_roi2.jpg',ROI)

# show images
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('new_image',new_image)
cv2.imshow('ROI',ROI)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

new_image after applying the mask:

[image]

cropped roi image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Threshold on the orange color
- Find the (largest) contour and get its bounding box
- Draw a white filled contour on a black background as a mask
- Create a copy of the input with an alpha channel
- Copy the mask into the alpha channel
- Crop the ROI
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# load the image
image = cv2.imread("frame50.jpg")

#color boundaries [B, G, R]
lower = (0, 70, 210)
upper = (50, 130, 255)

# threshold on orange color
thresh = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(big_contour)

# draw filled contour on black background
mask = np.zeros_like(image)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

# put mask into alpha channel of input
new_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
new_image[:,:,3] = mask[:,:,0]

# crop 
ROI = new_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
   
# save result 
cv2.imwrite('frame50_thresh.jpg',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('frame50_mask.jpg',mask)
cv2.imwrite('frame50_new_image.jpg',new_image)
cv2.imwrite('frame50_roi.png',ROI)

# show images
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('new_image',new_image)
cv2.imshow('ROI',ROI)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Mask Image:

[image]

New image with mask in alpha channel:

[image]

Cropped ROI

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, i get the following error,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "roi2.py", line 12, in <module>
    thresh = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'lowerb'

Comment: ok had to use, thresh = cv2.inRange(image, np.array(lower), np.array(upper))

Comment: Odd? Works fine for me using opencv 3.4.8 on python 3.7.5. Perhaps a version issue. What are your OpenCV and Python versions?

Comment: why won't cv2.imwrite('frame50_roi.jpg',ROI) work?only png works? How do I get it to work for jpg?

Comment: and if i print and see the data in ROI the starting aren't zeros. As well as, in the preview window, the data outside the circle isn't zero. And how can it be done for jpgs
I would like the data to be black and not transparent outside the circle

Comment: JPG does not support transparency. That is why you need PNG or TIFF

Comment: I in fact want the outer part to be black and not transparent.